# Does Spotfire provide any simple way of creating an "Other" category to group entries within a filter?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Right now, I am using a filtering scheme which only looks at the data of the 5 or 6 most common entries in the 'Clinic' field. But, there are a handful of other possibilities which might account for a few rows each. They are too inconsequential to include on their own (I am using pie charts and bar charts), but I would like these rows to be accounted for. For this reason, I would like to create an "Other" category which groups these entries together. What is the best way of doing this? I know I can create a calculated column that groups everything aside from the top 5 or 6 in an other category, but I thought there might be a way to keep working with the original column and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. In 6.5.x you will have to write a case statement that will specify everything that is not most common to other.

In 7.0.x you can go to insert binned column. Add the bottom you can use values to create a bin. Add the values you want to the bin and call them "Other". Of course if you look at the column created like this, it is a case statement. But it is a whole lot faster than writing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Following **phiver** I came out with this solution in Spotfire 6.5.2:

1. Add a calculated column
2. With something like this:

`If(DenseRank(Count([Formation]) OVER ([Formation]),"desc")<10, DenseRank(Count([Formation]) OVER ([Formation]),"desc") & " " & [Formation], "10 Other")`

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I used a pie graph, and entered it in the "colors" configuration.